# Expectation of characters in a string

Tags: probability, cryptography

What is the expected distance between two ’e’s in a random character stream where ’e’s occur 11% of the time?

Comment: You mean the expected distance between consecutive occurrences of 'e', I assume? (That is, with no other occurrences of 'e' between them?)

Answer (score 0):

The probability that a letter is an "e" is $11/100$.

Assume independence, a totally unreasonable assumption for a piece of real text, but a reasonable interpretation of the phrase "random character stream."

**Given** that the current letter is an "e", or even not given that information, the waiting time until the next $e$ has 
**geometric** distribution with parameter $p=11/100$. The mean waiting time is  $1/p$, so  $100/11$.

For a  geometrically distributed random variable $X$, the value of $X$ is the total number of trials until and including the first success.  The length of the gap is $1$ less than the waiting time, so has mean $89/11$.

Comment: Why is indepedence obviously incorrect? The stream could be, at each letter, pick a random number from $1$ to $100$ and if that number is less than $12$ write "e" otherwise write "x." Then each letter is independent.

Answer (score 0):

In a sequence of events where $A$ occurs in each of them independently with probability $p$, the expected distance between two occurrences of $A$ is $\frac{1}{p}$. So the mean distance between two e's is $100/11\sim 9$.

Comment: Or $89/11$ depending on the definition of "distance."